# infinite prompt loop problems

Tags: c, loops, input

my program is only to accept ints as inputs. if the 2 inputs are not ints or there are more than 2 inputs it is supposed to print"Usange: Subset n k (n and k are ints satisfying 0<=k<=n<=100)" and prompt the user to try again. if I give valid inputs the program works fine, but if the inputs are wrong it prints in an infinite loop. I don't know why the first 'if' works how I wanted but the second 'if' doesn't. any help is much appreciated, thanks.

int main() {

```
int n;
int k;
int i = 1;
int B[MAX_SIZE + 1];

try_again:


printf("subsets ");

if (( scanf_s("%d %d", &n, &k) == 2) && ((k < n) && (n < 100))) {
    printSubsets(B, n, k, i);
    goto try_again;
}

if ((scanf_s("%d %d", &n, &k) != 2) || ((k > n) || (n > 100))) {
    printf("\n");
    printf("Usange: Subset n k (n and k are ints satisfying 0<=k<=n<=100)\n");

    goto try_again;
}

else { goto try_again; }
```

EXIT_SUCCESS;

[here is the output after input of 'e e'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwZLT.png)

Comment: When `scanf` does not match input, it leaves the first non-matching character in the input stream. When you call `scanf` ahain, it fails again since the character is still in the stream. To try again with new input from the user, you need to read characters from the input (as with `getchar`) until a new-line character is read.

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read the _line_ of input, then parse it.

Comment: You've just discovered reason #5 out of the 17 reasons that `scanf` is not very good for robust user input.  Error handling is poor to nonexistent, and it's basically more trouble than it's worth to get right.  My advice to you is to either live with this imperfection in your program for now, or else start learning how to do input without using `scanf` at all.  (Don't worry: not using `scanf` doesn't make you some kind of weirdo; actually it puts you in good company.  Real programs don't use `scanf`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that `%d` will not consume anything that isn’t part of a valid decimal integer constant - if you type in a non-digit character for input, `%d` will never remove it from the input stream, and your code will keep failing on that character, leading to an infinite loop.

If you can’t guarantee your input is well-behaved, then you should read everything in as text and parse it manually.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define BUFSIZE 12 // 10 digits plus sign plus terminator

int getint( int *value, FILE stream)
{
  char inbuf[BUFSIZE] = {0};
  if ( fgets( inbuf, sizeof inbuf, stream ) )
  {
    char *chk;
    int tmp = strtol( inbuf, &chk, 10 );
    if ( isspace( *chk ) || *chk == 0 )
    { 
      *value = tmp;
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This function reads up to `BUFSIZE`-1 characters (or to the next newline) from the spcified stream with the `fgets` function.  That text is then converted to an integer value using `strtol`, which is saved to `tmp`.  The `chk` variable points to the first character in the string that *isn’t* part of a valid integer constant (i.e., not a decimal digit character).  If that character is whitespace or zero, then the string is a valid integer.  That integer value is assigned to the parameter `value` and the function returns 1 to indicate success.  Otherwise, `value` is left unchanged and the function returns 0 to indicate failure.

You’d call it from the main function like

```
if ( getint( &n, stdin ) && getint( &k, stdin ) && k < n && n < 100 )
```

Now, let’s talk about your program structure...

You’re making the `scanf` call twice, which you don’t need to do - your `if/else` block can simply be

```
if ( getint( &n, stdin ) && getint( &k, stdin ) && k < n && n < 100 )
  printSubsets(...);
else
  printf( “Usage...” );
```

Also, while there are cases where a `goto` can be the right answer, this isn’t one of them.  Instead, use a `for(;;)` loop to iterate until you successfully run `printSubsets`:

```
for (;;)
{
  printf( “subsets: ” );
  if ( getint( &n, stdin ) && getint( &k, stdin ) && k < n && n < 100 )
  {
    printSubsets(...);
    break;
  }
  else
    printf( “Usage...” );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're calling scanf two times, so reading 4 inputs.
If you want to apply both if to the "same scanf output" you would need save it.

Example:

```
a = scanf_f(..);
if(a == "expression1") { ... }
if(a == "expression2") { ... }
```

Comment: Calls inside an expression are executed/evaluated.*

Comment: After trying this the output is the exact same.